# Remote servers picking up incorrect IP, DSL router connected

Tags: linux, ip, port-forwarding, dsl

I have a server connected to a DSL router. If I go to whatismyip.com, I get an IP address, but I can't access the server from a remote location using that IP address. Instead I have to use the IP of the DSL router to connect to the server (SSH / HTTP). Is there a way to configure the router to allow connecting to the server using the server IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

You see the routers IP address because that is the publicly routeable address, your server's address will be in your private address space. The only way you can get to your server is to configure your router to do port-forwarding for particular services (like ssh & www).

Do be aware that your routers address will change occassionally so you might want to look into dynamic DNS if your project is long term.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably seeing a Web Proxy IP when you're accessing whatismyip.com.

Unless you know that there's a IP address range routed for you by your ISP (like a /29 range) then you're probably using NAT so port forwarding at your router onto a non-routeable address (192.168.0.0/24 for example) for services like SSH, using the router's IP, is the only access available.

Answer (score 2):

Find in yours DSL modem parameter **DMZ Zone** end put local ip addres of server to it. Now all connections to yours DSL modem whoud go to server.